# How to set the filters in Google Cloud Platform API Explorer?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I want to try a couple of APIs from GCP APIs Explorer. I have disks names starting with **Tri**. E.g. **Tri12345**
I want to find all disks starting with **Tri**.
I tried **Tri*** in the filter which is working fine giving me **Tri12345**.
When I try to set the filter as ***12345**, I am not getting any output. 
How to set the filters for GCP API Explorer in this case?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which API you are referring to? There are many GCP (Google Cloud Platform) APIs.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/list - this is the API I am referring to. I am not able to set the filter for start of the string.

Comment: I don't see anything on that page implying you can use wildcards in the filter parameter. However, filter appears to be optional, so what if you just omit the filter and instead write code to do the filtering on all of the results?

Comment: I have already done that. I fetched all the results and then written the code for filtering. I am curious to know Is this the limitation from GCP (Google Cloud Platform) side that we can not set the filter in the start like **name ="*snap"**?